# What's the difference between the three linux-image variants in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

For example, the following command yields `generic`, `server`, and `virtual`.

```
$ apt-cache search linux-image-3

linux-image-3.0.0-15-generic - Linux kernel image for version 3.0.0 on x86/x86_64
linux-image-3.0.0-15-server - Linux kernel image for version 3.0.0 on x86_64
linux-image-3.0.0-15-virtual - Linux kernel image for version 3.0.0 on x86/x86_64
```

What is the difference between the three?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [Ubuntu Server FAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq):

The **linux-image-server** package is a meta package that will install the latest Server kernel version, while the **linux-image-generic** package is a meta package for the latest Desktop kernel version. The server guide includes some details on the changes made in the Server kernel.

**linux-image-server** is used for both architectures x86 and amd64.

Which one you should use will depend on the type of system you have. If you have a 64 bit processor you can use the amd64 architecture, or the x86 architecture. However, if your processor is 32 bit you can only use the x86 kernel.

**Virtual kernel:**

The difference between the Virtual and Server kernels is that the Virtual kernel is intended to be utilized inside a virtual machine. The virtual kernel only includes the necessary drivers to run inside popular virtualization technologies such as KVM, Xen, and VMWare. The server kernel in contrast contains the necessary drivers to work with a wide range of hardware, and should be installed directly on host systems. Other than that, all other options are identical between the server and the virtual kernel.

Comment: Clear answer indeed. Now since "[Since 12.04, there is no difference in kernel between Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server since linux-image-server is merged into linux-image-generic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq#Which_kernel_versions_or_types_are_available_on_the_Ubuntu_Server_CD.3F)", what are the *actual* diffs between the generic/desktop and server images?